# Android AsyncTask ExceptionInIntilizationError

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Im trying to create a basic AsyncTask to get a certificate from the key store.

for some reason even the most simple AsyncTask doesnt work for me, i keep getting an error about ExceptionInIntilizationError.

This is the test code im using to just get a basic asynctask working:

```
public class Authenticator extends Activity {

PrivateKey privateKey = null;
String SavedAlias = "";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getCertificates("TEST");

    doSomething();

}

public void doSomething()
{
    new additionalStuff().execute();
}

public class AliasLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, X509Certificate[]> 
{
    X509Certificate[] chain = null;

    @Override protected X509Certificate[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
        android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();

        if(!SavedAlias.isEmpty())
        {
                try {
                    chain = KeyChain.getCertificateChain(getApplicationContext(),SavedAlias);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                }
        }
        else
        {
            this.cancel(true);
        }

        return chain;
    }
    @Override protected void onPostExecute(X509Certificate[] chain) 
    {
        try {
            privateKey = KeyChain.getPrivateKey(getApplicationContext(), SavedAlias);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        if (privateKey != null) {
            Signature signature = null;
            try {
                signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            try {
                signature.initSign(privateKey);
            } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}

public void getCertificates(String Host)
{
    KeyChainAliasCallback callBack = new KeyChainAliasCallback() {

        @Override
        public void alias(String alias) {
            if (alias != null) 
            {
                saveAlias(alias);
                //doSomething();
            }
        }
    };

    KeyChain.choosePrivateKeyAlias(this, callBack,
    new String[] {"RSA", "DSA"}, // List of acceptable key types. null for any
    null,                        // issuer, null for any
    null,      // host name of server requesting the cert, null if unavailable
    443,                         // port of server requesting the cert, -1 if unavailable
    null);                       // alias to preselect, null if unavailable

}

public void saveAlias(String alias)
{
    SavedAlias = alias;
}

public class additionalStuff extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void>
{
    String test = "This is a Test!!!";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) 
    {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) 
    {
        Log.d("DEEPAM", "THIS IS A TEST");
        return;
    }

}
}
```

Why does this fail? =(

** UPDATE **
I made the changes to add the @Override on the postexcecution and the parameters Void Void and it still comes up with the same ExceptionInInitilizationError =(

** UPDADE **

Im guessing i cannot create a new thread using Asynctask in the UI, which is probably why it was failing before, is there anyway i can get the AsyncTask to be called once the user has selected a certificate?

Comment: Maybe protected void onPostExecute(Void Void) (forget parameters)

Comment: could you post the stacktrace? also, please stick to naming convention, i.e. use `AdditionalStuff` instead of `additionalStuff` for class name.

Comment: oh, and i believe it should be `protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Figured out the problem, whatappserv, Vladimir and n_benbourahla mentioned probably would have been problems later on once my initial mistake had been fixed.

essentially i forgot to add in a bit of code that is using the execution.
I am calling the doSomething.execute() in the callback of a KeyChain.choosePrivateKeyAlias.

which it looks like putting it outside that and the asynctask works fine.

I still have the problem of how can i call the asynctask inside the callback from the keychain.choosePrivateAlias as it is essential that it is only run once that has executed. I will update the code with what i now have.

Answer (score 0):

Why your onPostExecute haven't the tag "@override" and any parameter ?